# segmentation fault when allocating a list from a file

Tags: c, list, file, memory-management, segmentation-fault

In this program i insert values read from a file in a list. In headers there are handles

**dizionario.h**

```
typedef struct dizionario* DIZ;
```

**lista.h**

```
typedef struct lista* LISTA;
```

In main i call the function init_diz that returns a pointer DIZ

**main.c**

```
FILE *fp;
DIZ d;
```

...

```
if((d=init_diz(&fp))==NULL)
    return EXIT_FAILURE;
```

**dizionario.c**

```
struct dizionario{
   LISTA head;
   LISTA tail;
};

DIZ init_diz(FILE **f)
{
    DIZ nuovo;
    nuovo=(DIZ)malloc(sizeof(struct dizionario));
    if(nuovo==NULL)
        return nuovo;
    if(!alloc_lista(&f, &(nuovo->head), &(nuovo->tail)))
        return NULL;
    return nuovo;
}
```

**lista.c**

```
struct lista{
    LISTA next;
    LISTA prev;
    char codex[N+1];
    char nome[MAXWORD+1];
    char cognome[MAXWORD+1];
    char data[N+1];
};
int alloc_lista(FILE ***fil, LISTA *testa, LISTA *coda)
{
    LISTA nuovo, prec=NULL;
    for(nuovo=*testa; !feof(**fil); nuovo=nuovo->next ){
        nuovo=(LISTA)malloc(sizeof(struct lista));
        if(nuovo==NULL)
            return 0;
        fscanf(**fil, "%s%s%s%s", nuovo->codex, nuovo->nome, nuovo->cognome, nuovo->data);
        nuovo->next=NULL;
        nuovo->prev=prec;
        prec=nuovo;
    }
*coda=prec;
return 1;
}
```

when i traverse the list to remove a node i take sigsegv

**main.c**

```
eliminazione(d);
```

**dizionario.c**

```
void eliminazione(DIZ diz)
{
    elimina((diz)->head);
}
```

**lista.c**

```
void elimina(LISTA testa)
{
    LISTA h;
    char codice[N+1];
    printf("inserisci il codice dell'elemento da eliminare: ");
    scanf("%s", codice);
    for(h=testa; h!=NULL; h=h->next){
        if(strcmp(h->codex, codice)==0){ /*SIGSEGV WHILE COMPARING THE FIRST ELEMENT of the list!!!*/
            h->prev->next=h->next;
            free(h);
            h=h->prev;
        }
    }
}
```

here is my file i tried to read

**file.txt**

s201532
gabriele
salvo
05/03/1994
s225632
matteo
turchetti
31/08/1994
s569874
bruno
pinci
05/09/1994
s564812
domenica
salvo
09/02/1981
s114455
giovannina
nasello
05/04/1950
s379152
bianca
pop
26/04/1996
s478125
gaia
ravazzolo
28/03/1996
s598741
francesco
martoscia
24/06/1975
s700265
giuseppina
salvo
24/06/1977
s112598
ernesto
giliberto
25/12/1920

Comment: *minimal* example? *one* file, no *irrelevant* things...

Comment: Run it with a debugger. And if you don't know how to use a debugger, it's time to start learning it.

Answer (score 0):

in your eliminia method you first free h and then try to access it.
you should do something like this:

```
LISTA temp;
...
...
temp = h->prev;
free(h);
h  = temp;
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the strcmp from the libC, so if you give a NULL pointer to strcmp it segfault !

```
int
strcmp (const char *p1, const char *p2)
{
  const unsigned char *s1 = (const unsigned char *) p1;
  const unsigned char *s2 = (const unsigned char *) p2;
  unsigned char c1, c2;

  do
    {
      c1 = (unsigned char) *s1++;
      c2 = (unsigned char) *s2++;
      if (c1 == '\0')
    return c1 - c2;
    }
  while (c1 == c2);

  return c1 - c2;
}
```

It segfault at "strcmp(h->codex, codice)" if h->codex == NULL or if codice == NULL

Comment: You are right charlon but i don't understand why i have null pointer in testa, where is my fault in allocation?

Comment: I don't really know but the thing I know that you need to use GDB (or LLDB) to debug this kind of problem and this will improve your debug skill too. segfault will become fun after mastering this type of debuggers :)